# size of array '__curl_rule_01__' is negative

Tags: compilation, git, curl

I'm struggling with an error whilst trying to compile GIT.  I've searched Google and the GIT source issues/bugs for similar issues but i've not found anything to help me.

Originally I received the following error

```
root@teemo:/usr/src/git# make prefix=/usr install install-doc install-html install-info;
    CC http-push.o
In file included from cache.h:39:0,
                 from http-push.c:1:
/usr/include/zlib.h:34:19: fatal error: zconf.h: No such file or directory
 #include "zconf.h"
                   ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [http-push.o] Error 1
```

I created a symbolic link inside `/usr/include/` to the missing file as follows (after I had installed/compiled the latest/development version)

```
root@teemo:/usr/src/git# ln -s /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/zconf.h /usr/include
```

Which brings me to the current issue, which I am confused as to how to solve.  If someone could advise it would be greatly appreciated.

```
root@teemo:/usr/src/git# make prefix=/usr install install-doc install-html install-info;
    CC http-push.o
In file included from /usr/include/curl/curl.h:35:0,
                 from http.h:6,
                 from http-push.c:5:
/usr/include/curl/curlrules.h:142:3: error: size of array '__curl_rule_01__' is negative
   __curl_rule_01__
   ^
/usr/include/curl/curlrules.h:152:3: error: size of array '__curl_rule_02__' is negative
   __curl_rule_02__
   ^
make: *** [http-push.o] Error 1
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Read higher up in `curlrules.h`. That error is intentionally forced as part of a test that checks the size of data types.

```
 * NOTE 2
 * ------
 *
 * Some of the following compile time checks are based on the fact
 * that the dimension of a constant array can not be a negative one.
 * In this way if the compile time verification fails, the compilation
 * will fail issuing an error. The error description wording is compiler
 * dependent but it will be quite similar to one of the following:
 *
 *   "negative subscript or subscript is too large"
 *   "array must have at least one element"
 *   "-1 is an illegal array size"
 *   "size of array is negative"
 *
 * If you are building an application which tries to use an already
 * built libcurl library and you are getting this kind of errors on
 * this file, it is a clear indication that there is a mismatch between
 * how the library was built and how you are trying to use it for your
 * application. Your already compiled or binary library provider is the
 * only one who can give you the details you need to properly use it.
```

Your version of libcurl was built with different options than you're using in your current git build. (it could be 32 vs 64 bit)

Knowing what platform you're on and your build options might be enough others to help resolve it. If this is the common case, and you're on Linux or another supported platform, it'd be easier just to install a prebuilt binary using the native software management. [Git downloads](https://git-scm.com/downloads)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I guess I should have checked there first.  Although, it turns I don't have that note in my `curlrules.h` and i'm running version **7.35.0**

Comment: The history on github looks like that comment has been there since the first version, but maybe yours was modified. Nonetheless, you can see the whole file at https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/master/include/curl/curlrules.h, or download the latest version.

Comment: I accepted - although this doesn't solve the problem, it prompted me to recompile curl again with the right resources/paths

Comment: I think that is the solution. The test is in there to see if the libcurl binary matches the configuration of the current build environment. It detects that it doesn't, and errors out. So the fix is to either get a new curl binary build that does match, or simply include building curl in the same environment as you are using to build your application.

Comment: In my case, I accidentally used the include path of the source directory, instead of the include path in the build directory. Things like this are hard to spot when your eyes are tired...

Comment: Btw, these related files were removed in libcurl, see this issue -- https://github.com/curl/curl/issues/1456

Answer (score 0):

In case system reports  `__curl_rule_01__` or `__curl_rule_02__` is negative make the following changes to `/usr/include/curl/curlbuild.h`:

Add the following lines:

- `define CURL_SIZEOF_LONG 4`
- `define CURL_SIZEOF_CURL_OFF_T 4`

(Or replace similar lines if these are already defined)

Comment: Btw, these files files were removed in libcurl, see this issue -- https://github.com/curl/curl/pull/1383