# Build libcurl on MacOSX with 32 bit support and custom OpenSSL version

Tags: macos, libcurl, configure

I'm having some serious trouble building `libcurl` on Mac OSX version 10.12.6.

I need a specific version of the static library (7.40.0), linked with a specific version of OpenSSL (1.0.2c), with 32-bit architecture support.

I found the source code on the official site, and ran the configuration script with which seemed to me the correct parameters:

```
curl-7.40.0> CPPFLAGS="-I/Users/me/Documents/Projects/3rdparty/openssl/MacOSX/openssl-1.0.2c/include/"
LDFLAGS="-L/Users/Documents/Projects/3rdparty/openssl/MacOSX/openssl-1.0.2c/"
./configure --disable-shared --build=i386-darwin --with-ssl
```

where:

- `CPPFLAGS` specifies the folder of the OpenSSL headers;
- `LDFLAGS` specifies the folder of the OpenSSL libraries (`libssl.a`, `libcrypto.a`);
- `--disable-shared` disables the build of the dynamic library (no `libcurl.dylib` output);
- `--build=i386-darwin` configures the build for Apple 32-bit target architectures;
- `--with-ssl` enables SSL options.

However, this call fails for two reasons:

1. Looking in the configure output, I read that "`host system type`" is set to `i386-darwin`, as the target. I can fix this by specifying that `--host=x86_64-darwin`;
2. I get that SSL is actually not enabled:

   ```
   configure: WARNING: SSL disabled, you will not be able to use HTTPS, FTPS, NTLM and more.
   configure: WARNING: Use --with-ssl, --with-gnutls, --with-polarssl, --with-cyassl, --with-nss, --with-axtls, --with-winssl, or --with-darwinssl to address this.
   ```

Of course I can address this by specifying `--with-darwinssl`, but when I do I get the following warning:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/me/Documents/Projects/3rdparty/openssl/MacOSX/openssl-1.0.2c'
```

And the OpenSSL library I'm trying to link is ignored.

Finally, if I try to remove `CFLAGS`and  `LDFLAGS` for SSL (just to see if the simplest call works):

```
./configure --build=i386-darwin --disable-shared --with-darwinssl
```

When I do, the `configure` and `make` scripts end well. If I try to include the `curl` headers in a sample source code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#include "curl/curl.h"
```

and specify the `curl-7.40.0/include` directory in XCode Headers search path, I get semantic issues:

```
curl-7.40.0/include/curl/curlrules.h:143:6: '__curl_rule_01__' declared as an array with a negative size
curl-7.40.0/include/curl/curlrules.h:153:6: '__curl_rule_02__' declared as an array with a negative size
```

I found the issue described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35181744/size-of-array-curl-rule-01-is-negative). If I go and check the `curlbuild.h` `#define`s, I find that the `CURL_SIZEOF_LONG` is 8, but is definitely defined. The project is compiled with Architecture i386.

Finally, if I try to simplify things even more and run an agnostic:

```
./configure --disable-shared --with-darwinssl
```

and switch the sample project architecture back to Universal 32/64 bits, when I link I get a bunch of weird errors:

```
"_ber_free", referenced from:
"_inflate", referenced from:
"_inflateEnd", referenced from:
"_inflateInit2_", referenced from:
"_inflateInit_", referenced from:
"_ldap_err2string", referenced from:
"_ldap_first_attribute", referenced from:
"_ldap_first_entry", referenced from:
"_ldap_free_urldesc", referenced from:
"_ldap_get_dn", referenced from:
"_ldap_get_values_len", referenced from:
"_ldap_init", referenced from:
"_ldap_memfree", referenced from:
"_ldap_msgfree", referenced from:
"_ldap_next_attribute", referenced from:
"_ldap_next_entry", referenced from:
"_ldap_search_s", referenced from:
"_ldap_set_option", referenced from:
"_ldap_simple_bind_s", referenced from:
"_ldap_unbind_s", referenced from:
"_ldap_url_parse", referenced from:
"_ldap_value_free_len", referenced from:
"_zlibVersion", referenced from:
```

I am probably either missing something obvious here, or missing many little bricks along the way. Either way, I am completely lost and I'm wondering if my task is actually feasible.

I could 'recompile' the whole application in 64 bits, but I probably need *this* version of `libcurl` and *that* version of OpenSSL, and if I can't even get a sample application going there's no point in switching to the real thing (if you're curious about why I need this configuration, check [my other thread about `libcurl` problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45677925/unable-to-connect-to-cloudfront-from-macosx-client): the Windows client has no problem connecting and is using the aforementioned configuration).

Do you see any obvious mistake I am doing? Any help or illuminating question will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually missed many steps along the way, but let's follow the issues chronologically.

1) OpenSSL compilation

I rebuilt OpenSSL and INSTALLED it in my Documents folder, running:

```
./configure no-shared --openssldir=~/Documents/openssl-lib darwin-i386-cc
make
make install
```

The INSTALL step added the "lib" folder needed by the linker.

2) Compile `libcurl`

Before actually compiling `libcurl` I had to install `pkg-config`:

```
brew install pkg-config
```

Then I gave the correct configure command:

```
CPPFLAGS="-I/Users/me/Documents/openssl-lib -I/Users/me/Documents/openssl-lib/include"
LDFLAGS="-L/Users/me/Documents/openssl-lib/lib" LIBS="-ldl -lpthread" 
CFLAGS="-arch i386"
./configure --with-ssl=/Users/me/Documents/openssl-lib
    --disable-sharing -build=i386-darwin
```

NOW the `openssl` options are correctly configured, because:

1. `pkg-config` is installed;
2. I added a `CFLAGS -arch i386`

Once linked with the correct openssl version...

The job was not done yet! Because I still had to link binaries in my test application. Aside `libcurl` I had to link

1. `openssl` (yes, again)
2. `LDAP` (XCode includes a Framework for that)
3. `zlib` (adding a "Other Compiler Option" `-lz`

After which, my test program correctly connected with Cloudfront and showed the correct `curl` version.